# Convert to modern Objective-C syntax - Single file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, refactoring

Xcode does offer to convert a project to modern Objective-C syntax - **BUT**

Is it possible to **convert just a single file** to Objective-C 2.0 syntax?

Co-workers might not appreciated dozens or hundreds of changed files across the whole project when all I really had in mind was updating that awkward `NSArray` initializer syntax with [funky literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) in the file I'm currently working on.

Comment: Nope.  It's kind of an all or nothing deal.  If all you want to do is make a change this small for a larger file, it may be more appropriate to just define a regular expression so you can find and replace the proper lines with updated syntax.  For a small file, it can be done by hand.

Comment: Kind of what I was afraid to read/hear.. Sure, all refactorings can be done manually - but IDEs are there to make our lifes easier, right? :-)

Comment: One would hope, but this *is* Xcode we're talking about...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the final step of the "Refactor to modern Objective-C syntax" process you can select
which files should be modified:

[image]

In this example, only main.m is updated and AppDelegate.m is left unchanged.

Comment: Thanks - I suppose this is as good as it gets for Xcode 5! Still a mess if that final dialog lists dozens of files (or close to 500 as in our legacy project...)

Comment: Convertor to modern objective-c syntax of Xcode 10 seems does not work any more.

Comment: @DawnSong: You are right, it does not work anymore. You should file it as a bug report.